# PostgreSQL - Unexpected Behavior: PRIMARY KEY (NEW.id reference in Trigger Function) increments during failed INSERTS, despite row count unchanged

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I am experiencing an issue while debugging this postgresql trigger function. While attempting to insert data and observe its result, I am getting errors (expected during the debug process). There have been no successful inserts, and all tables have 0 rows despite my (failed) tests while debugging -- this is also expected. But, for some unknown reason, my reference to `NEW.id` is incrementing with each failed test. `NEW.id` is supposed to be the primary key value of the record being inserted. The primary key is supposed to auto-increment after each successful insert (like 0, 1, 2, 3, ...). So how is it possible that `NEW.id` is incrementing with each failed record INSERT despite row count remaining at 0?

This behavior is preventing me from moving forward in testing. This behavior breaks the logic I am relying on to keep the database clean and structured.

Below I will provide a copy of the trigger function. Below that, I will provide a copy of the error as I see it,

```
-- FUNCTION: public.distribute_process_data()

-- DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS public.distribute_process_data();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.distribute_process_data()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    time_stamp timestamp;
    source_id int;
    medium_id int;
    country_id int;
    request_id int;
    error_id int;
    success bool;
BEGIN
    select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP into time_stamp;

    INSERT INTO
        sources(source, category)
        VALUES(NEW.source, NEW.category) ON CONFLICT (source) DO NOTHING
        RETURNING id INTO source_id;

    INSERT INTO
        mediums(sources_id, medium)
        VALUES(source_id, NEW.medium) ON CONFLICT (sources_id, medium) DO NOTHING
        RETURNING id INTO medium_id;

    INSERT INTO
        countries(country)
        VALUES(NEW.country) ON CONFLICT (country) DO NOTHING
        RETURNING id INTO country_id;

    INSERT INTO
        requests(sources_id, request_jsonstring, request_md5hash)
        VALUES(source_id, NEW.request, md5(NEW.request::text)) ON CONFLICT (request_md5hash) DO NOTHING
        RETURNING id INTO request_id;

    CASE
        WHEN NEW.error IS NOT NULL THEN
            INSERT INTO
                errors(timestamp, processes_id, error)
                VALUES(time_stamp, NEW.id, NEW.error)
                RETURNING id INTO error_id;
            select FALSE INTO success;
        ELSE
            select NULL INTO error_id;
            select TRUE INto success;
    END CASE;

    INSERT INTO
        processes(
            id, timestamp, requests_id, errors_id, sources_id, mediums_id, countries_id, successful,
            date, web_visits, conversions, ad_impressions, ad_clicks, ad_cost, companygo_ad_visits,
            companynetwork_ad_visits, companygo_ad_visits_bounce_rate, downloads_desktop, downloads_mobile,
            initiated_registrations, completed_registrations, paid_users, revenue
        )
        VALUES(
            NEW.id, time_stamp, request_id, error_id, medium_id, country_id, success,
            NEW.date, NEW.web_visits, NEW.conversions, NEW.ad_impressions, NEW.ad_clicks, NEW.ad_cost,
            NEW.companygo_ad_visits, NEW.companynetwork_ad_visits, NEW.companygo_ad_visits_bounce_rate, 
            NEW.downloads_desktop, NEW.downloads_mobile, NEW.initiated_registrations, NEW.completed_registrations, 
            NEW.paid_users, NEW.revenue
        );
    RETURN trigger;
END;
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.distribute_process_data()
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

Here is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ForeignKeyViolation                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [4], line 1
----> 1 cursor.execute(sql)

ForeignKeyViolation: insert or update on table "errors" violates foreign key constraint "processes_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (processes_id)=(13) is not present in table "processes".
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "INSERT INTO
                errors(timestamp, processes_id, error)
                VALUES(time_stamp, NEW.id, NEW.error)
                RETURNING id"
PL/pgSQL function distribute_process_data() line 34 at SQL statement
```

Notice where it says `(processes_id)=(13)`. That value of `13` began at `1`. After each failed INSERT during debug, it incremented by `+2`. So it progressed like so: `1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 7 -> 9 -> ...`. Since it is referencing `NEW.id` though, the expected behavior is that it remains at value `1`. Because my tests are failing, therefore row count remains 0, therefore PRIMARY KEY should not be incrementing.

Any help or leads here is very much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Curious if this could be my issue: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/295341/insert-on-conflict-do-nothing-why-is-the-serial-number-incremented || For the record, I am very new to Postgres. I will investigate this issue here.

Comment: Gaps in sequences are to be expected. Sequences are non-transactional. Once a value is obtained a rollback won't rollback the sequence. This by design, there is nothing you need to do. The **only** job of a generated key is to be unique. The actual value is completely meaningless. 1,2 or 3 a just as good as 463832 or -4693 as long as the value is unique

Comment: [Create Sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html): *Because nextval and setval calls are never rolled back, sequence objects cannot be used if “gapless” assignment of sequence numbers is needed. It is possible to build gapless assignment by using exclusive locking of a table containing a counter; but this solution is much more expensive than sequence objects, especially if many transactions need sequence numbers concurrently.* Sequences back `IDENTITY` also so they will see the same gaps.

Comment: From here [Alter Sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altersequence.html) you can do `ALTER SEQUENCE <seq_name> RESTART` to get it back to the starting position.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks! I looked deeper into this, my logic was flawed because I was trying to insert an error into the errors table before inserting the process into processes table. Errors tale has a constraint for foreign key to the processes table, causing the error. I was confused and believed the error was caused by the gaps in sequence.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Now, I can successfully use the trigger error free, but after usage I find that no tables were updated. No records inserted anywhere, despite no error. Should I create a new issue for this?

Comment: Interesting that `ALTER SEQUENCE <seq_name> RESTART` can do this. Given I was confused about the true cause of  my problem, I don't think I actually need a gap-less sequence. You've spiked my curiosity though; do you happen to know if this method is safe for multi-threading (i.e., concurrent inserts)?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for this illustration. It was helpful for my understanding.